# Gazebo Hardware Requirement

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and ROS Hydro. I installed Gazebo 1.9 and executed initial mobile robot tutorials with SDF. But my system gets very slow while running Gazebo. I have 1GB RAM with Intel Pentium (R) Dual CPU E2200@ 2.20 GHz*2.
My motherboard is: ASUS P5KPL-AM EPU. Is there a minimum requirement for CPU and RAM while running Gazebo? What is that? Should I increase my RAM?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127566/gazebo-hardware-requirement/) by [mudassar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10726/mudassar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2014-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can better ask this question at http://answers.gazebosim.org/

But both your RAM and cpu are probably at the minimum. More ram would help but the CPU is also a bit slow.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0